# how extract important keywords from text including numbers?

Tags: python, regex, text

I am using stemming and NLP methods to extract keywords from text file.

I got output keywords:

```
keywords = ['the lounge lizards', 'jazz', 'john lurie', 'musical', 'albums', 'bass guitar', 'drums', 'edit', 'erik satie', 'erik sanko']

# now to get numeric significant keywords 
# Applied this reg ex 
re.findall(r'\w+\s\d+.*?\s\w+', content)

numeric_keywords = ['in 1978 by', 'History\n2 Past', 'members\n3 Discography',    'albums\n3.2 Live', 'June 4th, 1979', 'October 7,1986): "The Lounge', 'In 1984 the', 'early 1990s; prominent']
```

Any better way to extract numeric? Both output are from same file.

Comment: What is your source text and what exactly do you want to catch?

Comment: i want to extract significant number with following words from web articals, so that they can be used as keywords. For numeric keywords i am not getting any idea ?

Comment: Try this regex: `\w+\s(\d+(?:\.\d+)?).*?\s\w+`